# multiple level login form not working.. while submitting

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

**dont know why this form is not working.... while i submit this after putting username and password.. it donot show any thing after submission**

```
<?php 
 include "connect_to_mysql.php";
 if(isset($_POST['log']))
 {
 $user= $_POST['user'];
 $pass=md5($_POST['pass']);

   $sql=mysql_query("select* from login where user= '$user' AND pass='$pass'    LIMIT 3 ");
  $data=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  $UserName= $data['user'];   
  $Password= $data['pass'];
  $type= $data['type'];
  $name= $data['name'];

  if($user==$username && $pass==$password){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name']=$name;
  if($type=='admin')
  {
         header("location: index.php");
  }
  else if($type=='vender1')
 {
         header("location: vender1.php");
  }

 }




  else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();
  }
  }
  ?>
```

**database is created manually and login table has 5 columns named as id, name. user, pass, type.**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title> Log In </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
   </head>

   <body>
   <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
   <br /><br /><br /><br />
   <div id="mainWrapper">
   <?php include_once("header.php") ?></div>
   <div id="pageContent"><br /><br /><br />
   <div align="right" style="margin-right:24px; color:#FF0000">
   <h2>Please Log In To Manage the Inventary</h2>
   <br /><br />
   <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="login.php">
     <h2 style="padding-right:200px;">User Name:</h2>
       <input name="user" type="text" id="user" size="40"   style="height:20px;" />
     <br /><br />
     <h2 style="padding-right:210px;">Password:</h2>
     <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" size="40" style="height:20px;" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />

    </form>
   <p>&nbsp; </p>
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   </div>

    </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

**i m stucked here.. please make me out of this**

Comment: Your code is SQL Injective and please use PDO, you are using deprecated functions like `mysql_query()`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you have error in SQL syntax 

Change `select*` to `select *`

Comment: i didnt get you.. please write down in code.. what you are saying

Comment: You can run your query like `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())` so you can see if your query ran or not

Comment: `$sql=mysql_query("select * from login where user= '$user' AND pass='$pass'    LIMIT 3 ") or die(mysql_error());`

change that line to this

Comment: select * is the answer my man.. i have checked that

Comment: You have used $UserName for declaration and used $username. Please check your code. :)

Comment: @deepsingh please accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: @Umair  this is not answer my man.. i have checked.. even this is not working

Comment: Did you replaced the line to which I have told in my answer, it will show the  if you have error in your MYSQL

Comment: yes i did that.. but its not showing any error

Comment: see  edits in my question now @deepsingh

Comment: @BlueRose its still not working my man

Comment: Is there any error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following code ,

```
   $sql=mysql_query("select* from login where user= '$user' AND pass='$pass'    LIMIT 3 ");
  $data=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  $UserName= $data['user'];   
  $Password= $data['pass'];
  $type= $data['type'];
  $name= $data['name'];

  if($user==$username && $pass==$password){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name']=$name;
  if($type=='admin')
  {
         header("location: index.php");
  }
  else if($type=='vender1')
 {
         header("location: vender1.php");
  }

 }




  else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();
  }
  ?>
```

You have not used $_POST['log'] in the form ....

In your code you have used **if(isset($_POST['log']))**  , i have removed that because you have not using 'log' in your form.

Comment: yes you should start from <?php . except the if(isset($_POST['log'])) { }

Comment: by your code.. only this part is working 
  else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();
  }

Comment: Check the username and password provided is exactly matching the login table.

Comment: yea.. its exactly matching my man.... when i give wrong password it takes me to else part .... when i gives right password it remains on the same part.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['log']))
       <input type="submit" name="log" id="log" value="Log In" />

if i do this inplacing of removing the    if(isset($_POST['log'])).

Comment: what u say about this @user

Comment: Yes you can do , But try to use **mysqli** Or **PDO** instead of **mysql**

Comment: ok......   its else part is working.. when password is wrong.. but when password is correct it donot go on index.php and stays on the same page.. can you tell me.. why this is happening man

Comment: @deepsingh Change the line _if($user==$username && $pass==$password)_ to _if($user==$UserName && $pass==$Password)_

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your query, you are writing `select*` but there should be a space like so `select *`

`$sql = mysql_query("select * from login where user= '$user' AND pass='$pass' LIMIT 3 ") or die(mysql_error());`

**EDIT**

Also YOU MUST HAVE TO PUT `session_start();` as the first line of your code... else it would not work.

So make this as your first lines of code

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); // to see if there is error in code
```

And also PHP varialble names are [case-sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php),

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. **The variable name is case-sensitive**.

So please change

```
if($user==$username && $pass==$password)
```

to

```
if($user==$UserName && $pass==$Password)
```

Comment: STILL MY MAN.. NOT WORKING

Comment: what is output on the page when you submit your form?

Comment: it just remain on the same page.. after submission.. and show the same page

Comment: if u have teamviewer .. plz come on my pc.. and check it